# SQL Combining two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

*(P.S. I am still learning SQL and you can consider me a newbie)*

I have 2 sample tables as follows:

**Table 1**

```
|Profile_ID|  |Img_Path|
```

**Table 2**

```
|Profile_ID|  |UName|   |Default_Title|
```

My scenario is, from the 2nd table, i need to fetch all the records that *contain* a certain word, for which i have the following query :

```
Select Profile_Id,UName from 
Table2 Where 
Contains(Default_Title, 'Test')

ORDER BY Profile_Id
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

(*Note that i am setting the `OFFSET` due to requirements.)*

Now, the scenario is, as soon as i retrieve 1 record from the 2nd table, i need to fetch the record from the 1st table based on the `Profile_Id`.

So, i need to return the following 2 results in one single statement :

```
|Profile_Id|   |Img_Path|

|Profile_Id|   |UName|
```

And i need to return the results in side-by-side columns, like :

```
|Profile_Id|   |Img_Path|   |UName|
```

*(Note i had to merge 2 `Profile_Id` columns into one as they both contain same data)*

I am still learning SQL and i am learning about `Union`, `Join` etc. but i am a bit confused as to which way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.UName
from table1 t1 join
     (select Profile_Id, UName
      from Table2
      where Contains(Default_Title, 'Test')
      order by Profile_Id
      offset 5 rows fetch next 20 rows only
     ) t2
     on t2.profile_id = t1.profile_id
```

Comment: This only returns the 1st table, not the 2nd one.

Comment: @Aousafrashid . . . It is a `JOIN`.  Just select the columns that you want.

Comment: Yep, right, was just dumb enough not to see that! +1 mate!

Comment: @Aousafrashid . . . Not "dumb".  Just not experienced.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT a.Profile_Id, a.Img_Path, b.UName
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.Profile_Id=b.Profile_Id
WHERE b.Default_Title = 'Test'
```

Comment: It only returns the columns from the 1st table. I need columns from both tables.

Comment: This will match the Profile_Id with 2nd table. If the Profile_Id is same then it will show.

Comment: If you need columns from the second table, simply add them into the select using the alias. e.g. select a.columnname1, b.columname1 etc.

Comment: Code only answers really smell bad. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.